# Offset Column in Range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code to set a range:

```
Set rngsearch = xGBP.Range("B1", Columns("B").Find(1, Cells(Rows.count - 1, "B")).Offset(-1))
```

This works fine. Then what I want is to offset this range to pick column E instead of B and tried:

```
rngsearch = rngsearch.Offset(0, 3)
```

My  test shows this returns an empty array. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second line of code is missing the Set command. When assigning an object (such as a range) you have to set the object variable equal to the object.

```
Set rngsearch = rngsearch.Offset(0,3)
```